# Why does $\mathrm{E}[e^{-X}] = 0$ imply $\mathrm{P}(X = \infty)=1$?

Tags: probability, moments

Came across the following problem:

[image]

with the following solution:
[image]

I can follow the whole solution, except for the last statement: $\mathrm{E}[e^{-X}] = 0, $ equivalently, $\mathrm{P}(X = \infty)=1.$
Can someone walk me through the steps of this conclusion?

Comment: For a rigorous solution, note that for any $N \gt 0,$ the zero expectation implies $\Pr(X \le N)=\Pr(e^{-X} \ge e^{-N}) = 0.$ This line of reasoning will not require you to perform potentially suspect operations with infinities.

Comment: Cross-post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3212483/321264

Comment: @whuber: A nice approach, but you can pretty easily add infinity as an allowable outcome of the random variable, giving it a mixture distribution on the closed reals.  It requires some elaboration of operations, but here is nothing particularly suspect about that approach in my view.  Indeed, *without* allowing infinity as an outcome, the probability statement is meaningless.

Comment: @Ben Yes, that is a well-established approach and I'm not trying to suggest it is suspect.  I am only warning against the possibility of less-principled uses of "infinity" in calculations that might be suggested by this notation.  One needn't create a numerical infinity to make sense of the statement. For instance, it can be taken to mean that for all $N\gt 0$ and $\epsilon\gt 0,$ $\Pr(X\le N)\lt \epsilon.$

Comment: Fair enough - I guess I just prefer to take the problem on its stated terms rather than reinterpreting it without the numerical infinity.  (I've always been a fan of using an explicit infinity element in lieu of limits where possible.  You still end up having to use limit properties implicitly in the operations, but it cleans up the notation a lot.)  Anyway, I think we agree on the dangers of misuse.

Comment: @Ben I like your approach too, but too many threads here on CV abuse the concept of infinity.  It's a common source of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1191818/why-does-e-raised-to-the-power-of-negative-infinity-equal-0 for explanations why $e^{-X}$=0 only in the limit as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

As for the additional step that $E[e^{-X}]=0$ implies $P(X=\infty)=1$, note that there is no value of X for which $E[e^{-X}] < 0$.  $E[e^{-X}] = P(X=\infty)*0 + (1-P(X=\infty))*E[e^{-X}|X < \infty]$.

$E[e^{-X}|X < \infty]$ is strictly positive, so $(1-P(X=\infty))*E[e^{-X}|X < \infty] = 0$ implies $(1-P(X=\infty))=0$ which implies $1=P(X=\infty)$.